# Javascript prompt box displays twice on form postback

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, postback, html-select

I am using a javascript function to submit a form containing a select box when the select option is changed.  This then triggers a javascript prompt box to appear if the value that was selected is set to a certain value (in this case "new cart" as this is for an e-commerce website). The javascript is successfully submitting the form upon option change, and when the specific value is selected, it does display the prompt box, however, it displays the prompt box twice, and I have no idea why.

Here is the code for my select box. It is in a class function.  It is working correctly.

```
public function printCartsList($id = null, $mini = "true"){ 

    print '<form method="POST" name="cartSelectForm" action="home.php">';

        print '<select name="cartList" id="' . $id . '" data-mini="' . $mini . '" onchange="submitCartForm()" data-icon="false">';

            print '<option value="newuniquecartid1234567890">*** New Cart ***</option>';

            for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->savedCarts); $i++){
                if(isset($_SESSION['activeCart']) && $_SESSION['activeCart'] != "new cart"){
                    $cart = new Cart();
                    $cart = unserialize($_SESSION['activeCart']);
                    if($cart->GetCartName() == $this->savedCarts[$i]->GetCartName()){
                        print '<option value="' . $this->savedCarts[$i]->GetCartName() . '" selected>' . $this->savedCarts[$i]->GetCartName() . '</option>';
                    }
                    else{
                        print '<option value="' . $this->savedCarts[$i]->GetCartName() . '">' . $this->savedCarts[$i]->GetCartName() . '</option>';
                    }
                }
                else{
                    print '<option value="' . $this->savedCarts[$i]->GetCartName() . '">' . $this->savedCarts[$i]->GetCartName() . '</option>';
                }
            }

        print '</select>';

    print '</form>';

}
```

Here is my javascript inside a different file.

```
//Display input box
function DisplayInputBox(){
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 
    today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

    var name = prompt("Enter a name for this cart", today);

    if(name != null){

        // Set a cookie containing the name of the new cart
        setCookie("newCartName",name,1);

    }
}


function submitCartForm(){
    var cookie = getCookie("newCartName");
    if(cookie == null){
        document.cartSelectForm.submit();
    }
}   


// Create a cookie object
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

// Get a cookie object
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1)
    {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1)
    {
        c_value = null;
    }
    else
    {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1)
        {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}
```

Here I have 2 functions.  The newCart function is where the javascript function that displays the prompt box is called. I included another function, addToCart(), because this function calls the newCart function at a different time, and I wanted to mention that when the addToCart function calls the newCart() function, it works fine.  The prompt box is only displayed once, and I get the correct value back from the prompt box.  Other than pointing that out, you can ignore that function because it does not interact with newCart in any other way.

```
function newCart(){
    $cart = new Cart();
    $customer = new Customer();

/************could this be the problem?*************/
    echo "<script>DisplayInputBox();</script>";

    if(isset($_SESSION['customer'])){
        $customer = unserialize($_SESSION['customer']);
    }

    $cart->SetCartName("newCart");

    $customer->AddCart($cart);

    $_SESSION['customer'] = serialize($customer);
    $_SESSION['activeCart'] = serialize($cart);

    //echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">';
}

function addToCart($item){

    $cart = new Cart();
    $customer = new Customer();
    $newCart = false;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['activeCart'])){
        $_SESSION['activeCart'] = "new cart";
        newCart();
        $newCart = true;
    }
    elseif($_SESSION['activeCart'] != "new cart"){
        $cart = unserialize($_SESSION['activeCart']);
    }
    else{
        newCart();
        $newCart = true;
    }

    $cart->AddToItems($item);

    if(isset($_SESSION['customer'])){
        $customer = unserialize($_SESSION['customer']);
    }

    if($_SESSION['activeCart'] != "new cart"){
        $customer->UpdateCart($cart);
    }
    else{
        $customer->AddCart($cart);
    }

    if($customer->GetLoggedInStatus() > 0){
        //$customer->SaveCarts();
    }

    $_SESSION['activeCart'] = serialize($cart);
    $_SESSION['customer'] = serialize($customer);

    if($newCart == true){
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">';
    }

}
```

Here is my last code snipped. This is where I handle the logic after I submit the form using javascript and where I handle the logic when the newCart function completes. At the bottom of this code snippet, inside if(isset($_SESSION['customer'])) is where I print out my select box. That then goes to my first code snippet, where onchange() I call the submitCartForm() javascript function in my second code snippet. After that, the if(isset($_POST['cartList'])) code below gets executed which, if the new cart option was selected, calls the newCart function in the 3rd code snippet. That then calls the DisplayInputBox() javascript function in the second code snippet. From this point, that function sets a cookie, which is checked in the code snippet below.  During this process, the the prompt box displays twice, and I do not get the correct value back.

```
                       <?php

                            if(isset($_COOKIE['newCartName'])){
                                $customer = new Customer();
                                $cart = new Cart();
                                if(isset($_SESSION['customer'])){
                                    $customer = unserialize($_SESSION['customer']);
                                }
                                else{
                                    $customer->SetLoggedInStatus = 0;
                                }
                                if(isset($_SESSION['activeCart'])){
                                    if($_SESSION['activeCart'] != "new cart"){
                                        $cart = unserialize($_SESSION['activeCart']);
                                        $cart->SetCartName($_COOKIE['newCartName']);
                                    }
                                }

                                $success = $customer->UpdateCart($cart);

                                if($success == false){
                                    $customer->AddCart($cart);
                                }

                                $_SESSION['activeCart'] = serialize($cart);
                                $_SESSION['customer'] = serialize($customer);

                                setcookie('newCartName',"",time()-3600);

                            }

                            if(isset($_POST['cartList'])){
                                $customer = new Customer();
                                if(isset($_SESSION['customer'])){
                                    $customer = unserialize($_SESSION['customer']);
                                }
                                $cartArray = array();
                                $cartArray = $customer->GetSavedCarts();

                                if($_POST['cartList'] == "newuniquecartid1234567890"){
                                    unset($_POST['cartList']);
                                    newCart();
                                }
                                else{   
                                    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($cartArray); $i++){
                                        if($cartArray[$i]->GetCartID() == $_POST['cartList']){
                                            $_SESSION['activeCart'] = serialize($cartArray[$i]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                            if(isset($_SESSION['customer'])){
                                $customer = new Customer();
                                $customer = unserialize($_SESSION['customer']);
                                $customer->printCartsList("select-cart","true");
                            }
                            else{
                                $customer = new Customer();
                                $customer->printCartsList("select-cart","true");
                            }
                        ?>
```

I am lost as to why this is happening. Like I said, it doesn't happen when the addToCart function calls newCart, only when I submit the select box form.  I would greatly appreciate any help you can offer.  I tried being thorough, but there is a lot of stuff here.  If I can clear anything up, let me know.  Thank you!

***EDIT***

Everything below this line is a condensed version of what is above. I will keep what is above for reference, but below is the streamline logic.

This is my select box.

```
    print '<form method="POST" name="cartSelectForm" action="home.php">';

        print '<select name="cartList" id="' . $id . '" data-mini="' . $mini . '" onchange="submitCartForm()" data-icon="false">';

            print '<option value="newuniquecartid1234567890">*** New Cart ***</option>';


        print '</select>';

    print '</form>';
```

When it's value is changed it triggers this javascript function:

```
function submitCartForm(){
    var cookie = getCookie("newCartName");
    if(cookie == null){
        document.cartSelectForm.submit();
    }
}
```

This if statement catches it (unnecessary code has been removed):

```
if(isset($_POST['cartList'])){
    if($_POST['cartList'] == "newuniquecartid1234567890"){
        unset($_POST['cartList']);
        newCart();
    }
}
```

This calls newCart function (unnecessary code removed, full function above)

```
function newCart(){

    echo "<script>DisplayInputBox();</script>"; 

}
```

This calls the DisplayInputBox javascript function (unnecessary code removed). This is where the prompt is being displayed.

```
function DisplayInputBox(){

    // today is defined in the full version of this code (see above if needed)
    var name = prompt("Enter a name for this cart", today);

    if(name != null){

        // Set a cookie containing the name of the new cart
        setCookie("newCartName",name,1);

    }
}
```

The DisplayInputBox javascript function above sets a cookie which is checked for here (code has been removed) (Basically the only thing relevant here is that I unset the previously set cookie. Probably not too important.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['newCartName'])){

    $success = $customer->UpdateCart($cart);

    if($success == false){
        $customer->AddCart($cart);
    }

    setcookie('newCartName',"",time()-3600);

}
```

Hope this is more clear.  Let me know if I still need further refinement.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is far too much for us to go through. Can you please edit this post and limit the code down to what generates the javascript prompt.

Comment: Ok. I have edited my post. I left the original stuff there for reference in case I removed too much, but for the streamlined version, just view everything below the edit.

Comment: *this comment doesn't aide in the discussion* @Ohgodwhy, your username is what I said when I saw this rather large question.